# xlrd unable to open .xls files from vendor

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have 100+ .xls files that I need to convert to .xlsx for pandas. All my googling says I should use xlrd and openpyxl to do it, but I'm stuck at the first hurdle.

The .xls files don't seem to be readable by xlrd.

```
    import xlrd    
    ref_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("Invoice_319593_2.xls")
    print (ref_workbook)
```

is throwing up the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 4, in <module>
    ref_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("Invoice_319593_2.xls")
  File "path", line 157, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "path", line 108, in open_workbook_xls
    bk.fake_globals_get_sheet()
  File "path", line 732, in fake_globals_get_sheet
    self.get_sheets()
  File "path", line 723, in get_sheets
    self.get_sheet(sheetno)
  File "path", line 714, in get_sheet
    sh.read(self)
  File "path", line 795, in read
    rc, data_len, data = bk_get_record_parts()
  File "path", line 680, in get_record_parts
    code, length = unpack('<HH', mem[pos:pos+4])
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

I've changed the full directory to just 'path' here to censor some personal info.

I've googled the error message but not found a solution. Does anyone have any ideas? Am I missing something obvious? I've manually converted the file to .xlsx and it works perfectly fine with pandas, openpyxl and xlrd but the .xls versions don't.

Comment: Hey, you are having a struct error ( check your error : unpack('<HH', ...)

Which is quite weird, what is your xlrd version : print (xlrd.__VERSION__) ???

Comment: Using Version 1.2.0

Comment: This will be very hard to reproduce, and also with your version ( is up to date ) this should not happen, please contact the developer of XLRD with your error + a brief description, and he will be able to improve the package..... sjmachin "at" lexicon.net

Comment: But to help you a little bit.... Use xlrd.DEBUG = 2 then     ref_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("Invoice_319593_2.xls"), this will give you precisely which sheet contains the error

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings when you open the xls in excel?  It's possible they're not valid xls files.

Comment: Sorry, so I should just put:

```
xlrd.DEBUG = 2
ref_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("Invoice_319593_2.xls")
```

and run that?

Comment: Opens perfectly fine in excel with no problems Tim.

Comment: https://ufile.io/m06oh8k2

Here is a link to one of the .xls files.